# How can i detect that an asset has been published from a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, events

So, i must write this Craft plugin to index documents as soon as they are published, though a special publication field used amongst different pages templates (including a matrix field !).

How can i use the publish event to detect that this special kind of assets (assets belonging to a special directory) have been used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [entries.onSaveEntry](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#entries-onSaveEntry) event to get entries as they're saved, check the publish date, then loop through its properties, and check the paths on any assets.

You'd probably also want to hook into [entries.onDeleteEntry](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#entries-onDeleteEntry) to de-index any assets from entries that get deleted.

***Please note:*** this won't auto-index entries that were scheduled to publish at a later date.

Comment: There are also events for assets: [Asset API Events](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#asset-api-events).

Answer (score 0):

The [Craft Introvert](https://github.com/iainurquhart/craft_introvert) might be what you're looking for...

[image]

Comment: Actually, disregard that. A post-caffeine re-read says I misread your question, sorry.